# Can't submit Mac app via xcode4 - Invalid Signature

Tags: xcode, macos, app-store, macruby

I keep getting this error:

*Invalid Signature - This error occurs when you have signed your app's installer incorrectly. There are two certs required for this process: the "3rd Party Mac Developer Application" cert and the "3rd Party Mac Developer Installer" cert. When signing your package, you need to ensure that you are using the Installer cert to sign your package. Ensure that you are specifying this cert when submitting your app via the Xcode Organizer or when running productbuild from the command line.*

I've googled, and have followed instructions but to no avail.

I have:

Projects > targets > build > code signing > 3rd Party Mac Developer Application:

Then when I go to archive and it opens up Organizer I go to submit I select the '3rd Party Mac Installer' key. But it still fails :(

Do I need to do anything else? Like clean and then build first? (Build for what? Or just select build? - Although I've tried pretty much all of them first, and then archive).

If it's of relevance I am using MacRuby, and had to do this first to set it up for xcode deployment: http://redwoodapp.posterous.com/macruby-and-xcode-4-build-a-self-contained-ma

Any help appreciated - I'm tearing my hair out here :(

Comment: You may do better asking this in the Apple developers forum.

Comment: Thanks - I will have to check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think this is finally sorted - thanks to Daniel from the MacRuby mailing list. I actually ended up creating a ticket with Apple, but hopefully they won't charge me for it now it's been fixed without them.

You can view the solution here: http://astonj.com/uncategorized/invalid-signature-error-on-submitting-app-to-the-mac-app-store/

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem lately. And this is a perfect chance to write down and share my own notes. :)

I am assuming you are using Xcode and Organizer (not application uploader)

### Step 1: Check Keychain Access.app.

You have to have two certificates (That you download from mac dev center). Each of these has to be linked with a private key.
In the picture, I have only one certificate "nacho4..." linked with a private key "nac...".  So I should go to the mac dev center and download my certificates in order to continue. Download them and drag them into the "login".

[image: I only have one certificate "nacho..." linked with a private key "nac...". Make sure you have two of these.]

### Step 2: Make sure you can build your app with the right configuration.

In my case, I setup three configurations.
Debug: can debug + no signing (for development)
Release: cannot debug  + no signing (mainly for internal betas, etc)
Distribution: cannot debug  + signing (for app store distribution)

Go to project "build info">"build signing">
Make sure that you are signing you code with the correct sign identity. Something like: "3rd Party Mac Developer Application. My Company Inc."
*If you can't see this then it means something wrong is with your certificates in Keychain Access.app. Check your certificate is linked with a private key
[image]

### Step 3 Make sure you are building the right configuration.

(Yeah, kind of obvious but it happened to me the last time. This is the reason you could be getting "Invalid signature") In the "Edit Scheme" panel , make sure you have the right configuration in the "Archive" section. In my case is "Distribution" (The default is "Release ")

[image]

Note that if you don't do this correctly you will get be able to submit your binary to Apple but minutes later you will get an "Invalid Signature". Because the certificates are fine but the app is not signed.

### Step 4: Build you app and submit it

Xcode>Product>Archive
[image]

The organizer will appear. Now just submit it.

**I have found that validating the archive is useless because sometimes even the validation fails I am able to submit my app without errors. I read this from other threads too so not only me. So if you are sure this is the version you want to submit to Apple. just press the submit button.**

You are asked your username and password.
Then, you get another menu to select the application (With has only one option, at least in my case) and then select the signing identity I think.
This is important! Make sure "3rd Party Mac Developer Installer" is selected and everything should work.

[image]

If you can't see "3rd Party Mac Developer Installer" option in the last menu then it means something is missing in your keychain. (The Installer certificate from the mac dev center)

Note that if you don't do this correctly you will be able to submit your binary but minutes later you will get an "Invalid signature" mail from iTunes Connect because the app probably could be well signed but the certificates Apple will se are incorrect.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Hi nacho4d thanks for the post. I seem to have most of that. But am a little lost on the configurations. Do I just go to to Editor > add configuration > and then duplicate from release - that's what I did to add the Distribution config. Then where do I edit this config and what do I need to change? I'm assuming like this: http://img.photobucket.com/albums/v160/azzzz/so1.png ? also here's a screengrab from the deployment tab http://img.photobucket.com/albums/v160/azzzz/so2.png - can you spot any errors or where I might be going wrong?

Comment: Hummm... you seem to have done it right. However you don't need to set that for the Debug configuration. Are you sure you have the 2 certificates with their keys in Keychain Access.app ?

Answer (score 5):

The other two answers are good checklists, but it didn't work for me.

My problem was that I had installed Xcode 3.2.6 on Lion (it doesn't work anyway, but that's another story). This corrupted the productutil app.

To fix it: install the BSD.pkg in the Packages folder of your Lion Installer.

Thanks to [Jacob Gorban](https://devforums.apple.com/message/507189#507189) to share his solution on Apple Devs Forums.

Comment: It's just incredible. Without this link, without Jacob trick - I'd spend days trying to solve this "issue"! +1 for the link!

Comment: I wish I'd read this before recreating all my certificates & provisioning profiles ! If you have 2 computer running Lion you can also copy productutil.app from /usr/libexec to another computer.